# Cannot backup Documents folder using LaunchAgent and bash

Tags: icloud, backup, bash, launchd

I use the open source borg backup tool to make a daily backup of my Documents folder which is also on iCloud drive. I use a LaunchAgent stored in my local library directory to execute a bash script which takes care of the backup. The script also does a backup of another folder which is not on iCloud drive and this works just fine. However, the documents folder is not properly backup up. Just an empty folder is created. If I run the bash script manually, then all works fine. I suspect it is some security measure by Apple that prevents the automatic backup of the folder. Can't help but think of this Apple ad

https://youtu.be/8CwoluNRSSc

Does anyone know how to solve this? And no, I don't want to use TimeMachine for a variety of reasons.

PS: Here is my agent file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.tom.snapborg</string>
<key>UserName</key>
<string>tom</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/tom/cloud/Dropbox/config/BashScripts/snapborg.sh</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>1800</integer>
    <key>Debug</key>
    <false/>
    <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check if it is a least 8 in the morning
[ `date +%H` -lt 8 ] && exit
# Check if last backup is at least one day old
lbd=$( cat $HOME/.logs/borg.log )
[ `date -v -1d +%Y%m%d` -lt "$lbd" ] && exit 
# Wait a bit for network and check whether server can be reached
sleep 20
ssh -q tom@redacted exit || exit
# Check if upload speed is >= 20MBit (requires speedtest, can be installed with homebrew)
speed=`/usr/local/bin/speedtest --no-download --single --csv | cut -d "," -f 8 | cut -d "." -f 1`
[ "$speed" -lt 20000000 ] && exit
# Unmount BORG repository in case it is mounted
mount | grep $HOME/Library/mount/borg > /dev/null && diskutil unmount $HOME/Library/mount/borg
# Define Repository
REPOSITORY=ssh://tom@redacted:22/home/tom/backup
# Directories to backup
DIR1=$HOME/cloud 
DIR2=$HOME/Documents
# Passphrase
export BORG_PASSPHRASE='redacted'
# Backup
osascript -e 'display notification "Backup in progress" with title "BORG STATUS"'
/usr/local/bin/borg create "$REPOSITORY"::'tml-{now:%Y-%m-%d}' "$DIR1" "$DIR2"
# Delete old backups
/usr/local/bin/borg prune "$REPOSITORY" --prefix 'tml-' --keep-daily=7 --keep-weekly=8 --keep-monthly=24                
osascript -e 'display notification "Backup complete" with title "BORG STATUS"'
# Write backup date into log 
date +%Y%m%d > $HOME/.logs/borg.log
```

Comment: I did, but I don't think this is where the problem lies, as everything works perfectly fine if I don't use the Documents folder as the folder to backup

Comment: Please edit your question and add the contents of the **snapborg.sh** file.

Comment: I did, again, I don't think this is where the problem lies, but it may be helpful for others.

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? If **Debug** is set to _true_ in the **plist** _file_ what does it show in **system.log**? Why do you have  **AbandonProcessGroup** set to _true_ in the **plist** _file_?

Comment: So, to clarify: the script runs as expected if launched manually, and the script works when called by launchd if ~/Documents is not the source?

Comment: @benwiggy yes to both

Comment: I'm running macOS 10.15.6, but am away from the system right now. I will need to check the logs later.

Comment: @user3439894 If I set Debug to true, system.log complains that the debug key is no longer respected and that I should remove it. I have AbandonProcessGroup set to true because I copied the plist file from another task. I don't think it does any harm in this case. I just tried, it certainly does not change the outcome if I set it to false.